# YII 2 relational data from third table

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have a database having relationship of three levels. cheque->account->customer. Now I am trying to retrieve data from all three table at same time using the following method.

```
$query = Cheque::find();
$query->joinWith(['account.customer']);
$query->orderBy('sr desc');
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
     'query' => $query,
]);
```

**Cheque Model:**

```
class Cheque extends \common\components\db\ActiveRecord {


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName() {
        return 'cheque';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['sr'], 'integer'],
            [['ID', 'account_ID'], 'required'],
            [['ID', 'account_ID', 'created_by', 'branch_ID', 'application_ID'], 'string'],
            [['serial_start', 'serial_end', 'status'], 'number'],
            [['created_on'], 'safe']
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels() {
        return [
            'ID' => 'ID',
            'account_ID' => 'Account  ID',
            'serial_start' => 'Serial Start',
            'serial_end' => 'Serial End',
            'created_on' => 'Created On',
            'created_by' => 'Created By',
            'branch_ID' => 'Branch  ID',
            'application_ID' => 'Application  ID',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'sr' => 'ID'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getAccount() {
        return $this->hasOne(Account::className(), ['ID' => 'account_ID']);
    }


    public static function getActiveChequeBook($account_ID) {
        return Cheque::findAll(['account_ID' => $account_ID, 'status' => array_search('Active', \common\models\Lookup::$cheque_status)]);
    }
    }
```

But executing this I get the following error:
**pre>Exception 'yii\base\InvalidCallException' with message 'Setting read-only property: common\models\Account::customer'**

Comment: update the answer and show the account.customer relation please ..

Comment: show your Cheque model

Comment: @scaisEdge have a look at it now

Comment: I see you have already solved. .. well ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property customer in your common\models\Account model has no setter (only getCustomer method exists). Check you model and add appropriate property to class.